# Bitmasking and bitwise operations to extract last N bits in C

Tags: c, pointers, char, bit-manipulation, function-definition

I am facing a small issue in my C code

Essentially I am reading in a binary file and have extracted the instructions, each instruction is 4 bytes long and each instruction is 32 bits in size.

I have a program counter that starts at `0` and finishes at address `1024` and reads 4 bytes at a time

So

- instruction 0 = program counter @ 0,
- instruction 1 = program counter @ 4

Now that is not the issue, my code is reading the contents of the file correctly

**The issue I have is this:**

I wish to store return a pointer to the last 7 bits of instruction

So if I have the instruction @ program counter 0 =

`01111111111100000000000100010011`

Which equivalent hexadecimal representation is:

```
unsigned char instruction[INSTRUCTION_SIZE] = { 0x7F, 0xF0, 0x01, 0x13 };
```

Where `INSTRUCTION SIZE` is `4` since each instruction is 4 bytes thus 32 bits long.

I wish to return a variable that contains the last 7 bits so in our case `0010011`

Now, I have  a simple function that can print the last 7 bits

```
void print_first_instruction(unsigned char *instruction) {
    unsigned char value = instruction[0];
    unsigned char last_seven_bits = value & instruction[0];

    char bit0 = 0x00;
    printf("\nLast 7 bits in binary: ");
    for (int i = 6; i >= 0; i--) {
        bit0 |= (last_seven_bits >> i) & 0x01; // shift the bits and use bitwise OR to assign the bits to bit0
        bit0 <<= 1; // shift bit0 to the left to make space for the next bit
        printf("%d", (last_seven_bits >> i) & 0x01);

        if (bit0 == 0x13) {
            printf("Add command");
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *file;
    char *filename = "print.mi";
    int i, j;
    long filesize;

    file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error: could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
    filesize = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);

    // read the file and store its contents in instruction_memory
    for (i = 0; i < filesize; i += INSTRUCTION_SIZE) {
        fread(&blob.instruction_memory[i], 1, INSTRUCTION_SIZE, file);
    }
    for (program_counter = 0; program_counter < INSTR_MEM_SIZE; program_counter += INSTRUCTION_SIZE) {
        unsigned char instruction[INSTRUCTION_SIZE];
        for (int j = INSTRUCTION_SIZE - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            instruction[j] = blob.instruction_memory[program_counter + j];
        }
        print_first_instruction(instruction);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

This code  prints the last 7 bits of the first instruction

The first instruction is `01111111111100000000000100010011`

Thus it extracts  `0010011`

Now I wish to write some code that checks if the last bit is equivalent to `0010011`

In this case it obviously is so I want to print to standard output ("The add operation") has been found

How do I go about doing this.

Hence I also want to store the last 7 bits, in case I wish the function to consume other instructions OTHER than the first one

Comment: Passing the array `unsigned char instruction[INSTRUCTION_SIZE] = {0x7F, 0xF0, 0x01, 0x13};` to the function `print_first_instruction` doesn't print `0010011`. https://wandbox.org/permlink/1GXKko1jqR4lPnOY

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to shift bit by bit. Belew you have an example of the function converting to uint32_t depending on endianess (byte order) and extracting n-bits from it

```
uint32_t extractLastBits(const uint32_t val, int nbits)
{
    uint32_t mask = ((1ULL << nbits) - 1);
    return val & mask;
}

uint32_t touint32(const void *ptr, const size_t offset, int reverse)
{
    const unsigned char *cptr = ptr;
    uint32_t result;

    if(!reverse) memcpy(&result, cptr + offset, sizeof(result));
    else result = (uint32_t)cptr[0] << 24 | 
                  (uint32_t)cptr[1] << 16 | 
                  (uint32_t)cptr[2] << 8 | 
                  (uint32_t)cptr[3] << 0;
    return result;
}


int main(void)
{
    //little indian
    char arr[] = {0x13, 0x01, 0xf0, 0x7f};
    printf("0x%"PRIx32"\n", extractLastBits(touint32(arr, 0, 0), 7));

    //big endian
   unsigned char instruction[] = { 0x7F, 0xF0, 0x01, 0x13 };
    printf("0x%"PRIx32"\n", extractLastBits(touint32(instruction, 0, 1), 7));

}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/n4xhhrKfG

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica 

Answer (score 1):

The 32-bit instructions seem to be stored in memory in big endian format, ie: with the most significant byte first and the least significant byte last.  For this byte ordering, to extract the least significant 7 bits, you can just mask the low 7 bits of the 4th byte:

```
    bits = instruction[3] & 0x7F;
```

Be careful that the order of bytes in most desktop and laptop computers today is little endian, so in order to convert from file contents to 32-bit instructions requires specific code:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t get_opcode(unsigned char instruction[4]) {
    return ((uint32_t)instruction[0] << 24) |
           ((uint32_t)instruction[1] << 16) |
           ((uint32_t)instruction[2] <<  8) |
           ((uint32_t)instruction[3] <<  0);
}
```

Luckily, the above code compiles to only 1 or 2 instructions on most platforms.

Answer (score 0):

To extract last 7 bits from the last element of a character array (or sub-array) that contains 4 elements you should use mask `0x7F`.

So a function that returns 7 bits of the last element of a character array with 4 elements can look the following way

```
unsigned char extract_last_7_bits( const unsigned char *value )
{
    return  *( value + 3 ) & 0x7F;
}
```

If you need then you may change the return type from `unsigned char` to `int`.

In the caller of the function you can write for example

```
if ( extract_last_7_bits( instruction ) == 0x13 )
{
    puts( "Add command" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- The shift should occure *before* adding a bit. Otherwise, an extra space will be added to the value and finally the value will be stored as `0x26` (doubled) instead of `0x13`.
- The comparision against the desired value `0x13` should occure *after* the loop to extract bits, not in each iteration.

```c
    void print_first_instruction(unsigned char* instruction) {
        unsigned char value = instruction[0];
        unsigned char last_seven_bits = value & instruction[0];
    
        char bit0 = 0x00;
        printf("\nLast 7 bits in binary: ");
        for (int i = 6; i >= 0; i--) {
            bit0 <<= 1; // shift bit0 to the left to make space for the next bit
            bit0 |= (last_seven_bits >> i) & 0x01; // shift the bits and use bitwise OR to assign the bits to bit0
            printf("%d", (last_seven_bits >> i) & 0x01)
        }
    
        if(bit0 == 0x13){
            printf("Add command");
        }
    }
```